# I am using apollo and i can not get data from response

Tags: android, graphql, apollo

i am learning apollo and graphql in android now i have response but when fetch any data app give me this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.rami.ordersapp.AllOrdersQuery$Data.fetchOrders()' on a null object reference
```

Code:

```
    MyApolloClinet.getMyApolloClinet().query(AllOrdersQuery.builder().build())
           .enqueue(new ApolloCall.Callback<AllOrdersQuery.Data>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(@NotNull Response<AllOrdersQuery.Data> response) {
                  // Log.e("response", response.data().toString());
                   Log.e("response", response.data().fetchOrders().get(0).vendorName());

               }

               @Override
               public void onFailure(@NotNull ApolloException e) {

               }
           });
}
```

Comment: can you post response  ?

Comment: @abdullahyousry

Comment: 2019-08-06 12:15:23.412 12682-12730/com.rami.ordersapp E/response: [Error{message='Unauthorized', locations=[Location{line=1, column=25}], customAttributes={path=[fetchOrders]}}]

Comment: you are getting an error there is no fetchOrders() it will return 0 you should check for it's existence and no error occurred first

Comment: the problem is  [Error{message='Unauthorized',  and it solved ty